# Lenovo X220: Wifi issue

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop, hardware, lenovo

I have a problem with my wifi on my lenovo x220 using Xubuntu 15.04.
Sometimes I'm connected to the network but I can't use the network (ping, traceroute, etc. ...).

Troubleshooting:
I have to reboot my pc. Turn the wifi off and on again **isn't** helping.

The problems occurs especially when I turn my pc in sleep mode and back again. But sometimes it appears without the sleep mode.

Wifi-Chip:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`, its a PITA but works. You can also create a shortcut with `pkexec systemctl restart network-manager.service` (pkexec is a GUI _sudo-like_ tool).

Answer (score 0):

Many but not all X220s have a hardware or firmware issue that causes them to lose the wifi device after sleep.  It affects windows also.

Hibernate should be OK.  If you have an SSD drive installed, that doesn't hurt too much, and fortunately the x220 has an MSATA drive as well as the 2.5" drive bay